# Disable ContextMenu\right click on a Gridview row for a particular condition

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to wpf.
I have a grid in wpf  project

```
 <GridView x:Name="Train_View_Grid">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status"/>
                    </GridView>
```

which has a context menu (right_Click) which appears on right click.

I have to disable this right click for a row whose status is finished.(one of the column is status whose value can be finished or running)
But if the status is running we have to show right click menu.

```
  private void PEGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            hideContextMenu();
        }

private void hideContextMenu()
{  
                if (Train_Details_View.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRowView drv = Train_Details_View.SelectedItems[0] as DataRowView;

                    String journey_status = drv.Row["Status"].ToString();
                    if (journey_status.Equals("Finished"))
                    {
                        ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                    }
                    }

    }
```

and i called it on the grid of context menu as

```
<Grid x:Name="Train_Info_Pnl" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="PEGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" >
```

Is my code above correct and where should i call this?
If my code is wrong how can i correct it..

Comment: You disable right click by overiding the OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown event (handled to true), do not forget about the OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp as well. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes how can i do it.. i am new in wpf i don't know how to call these events and create them

Comment: Something like: protected override void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {...}
Google for OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown / Up and you will solve it I'm sure. Not at a computer right now so can't verify it but it should work...

Comment: Why do you have `if (Train_Details_View.SelectedItems.Count == 1)` twice in your code?

Comment: @erikduvet yes i tried it but its not working

Comment: How did you event look like then? Error messages?

Comment: @erikduvet i have edited my question by implementing what u suggested please see.. as far as what you said in your first comment OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown event (handled to true) i am not getting that..

Comment: @franssu ok my bad.. i am not here to argue with highly intelligent programmers like you..sometimes we are desperate for answers in short time and make mistakes..and as i have mentioned it i am new to wpf yes my knowledge is very limited..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant set a Trigger on ContextMenuService.IsEnabled. Here is a pure xaml working sample :

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LV">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <Label Content="Your menu item..."/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" 
                                Header="IsFinished"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <ListView.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.IsChecked, 
                                                   ElementName=LV}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.IsEnabled" 
                                Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>

        <CheckBox IsChecked="False"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="True"/>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```